# ARRAYFORMULA not expanding

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have the following ARRAYFORMULA entered into cell D2, and it seems like it should be expanding downward throughout the entire column (I'll do the "check for blank A2" addition to the formula once this part works correctly), but nothing is expanding.  Where have I gone astray?

Here's the formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A:$J,"select count(E) where (C contains '"& $A2:A &"' or C contains '"& $B2:B &"') and (E) Contains 'Option' label count(E) ''"),0)+
IFERROR(QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A:$J,"select count(F) where (C contains '"& $A2:A &"' or C contains '"& $B2:B &"') and (F) Contains 'Option' label count(F) ''"),0)+
IFERROR(QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A:$J,"select count(G) where (C contains '"& $A2:A &"' or C contains '"& $B2:B &"') and (G) Contains 'Option' label count(G) ''"),0)+
IFERROR(QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A:$J,"select count(H) where (C contains '"& $A2:A &"' or C contains '"& $B2:B &"') and (H) Contains 'Option' label count(H) ''"),0)+
IFERROR(QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A:$J,"select count(I) where (C contains '"& $A2:A &"' or C contains '"& $B2:B &"') and (I) Contains 'Option' label count(I) ''"),0))
```

[image]

A link to a copy of the spread follows:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14E1QEfcTYiwOG_gORkc8YoRuWEPM7FweLljj0hQCQTc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: because 2nd parameter of query does not support arrays. share a copy of your sheet

Comment: thank you!  I added link to a copy of the spread to the end of the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(TRIM(B2:B)="",,IFNA(IFNA(VLOOKUP((B2:B), 
 QUERY({IFNA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT('Form Responses 1'!C2:C, "\b"&TEXTJOIN("\b|\b", 1, (B2:B))&"\b"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT('Form Responses 1'!C2:C, "\b"&TEXTJOIN("\b|\b", 1, TRIM(A2:A))&"\b"))), 
 MMULT(N(REGEXMATCH('Form Responses 1'!E2:I, "(?i)Option")), {1;1;1;1;1})}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"), 2, 0), VLOOKUP(TRIM(A2:A), 
 QUERY({IFNA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT('Form Responses 1'!C2:C, "\b"&TEXTJOIN("\b|\b", 1, (B2:B))&"\b"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT('Form Responses 1'!C2:C, "\b"&TEXTJOIN("\b|\b", 1, TRIM(A2:A))&"\b"))), 
 MMULT(N(REGEXMATCH('Form Responses 1'!E2:I, "(?i)Option")), {1;1;1;1;1})}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"), 2, 0)), 0)))
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C="",,IFNA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, QUERY({TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 REGEXEXTRACT('Form Responses 1'!C2:C, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, "("&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(UNIQUE(
 FILTER({Sheet3!B2:B; Sheet3!A2:A}, {Sheet3!B2:B; Sheet3!A2:A}<>""))), " ", ").+(")&")"))),,9^9))) , 
 MMULT(N(REGEXMATCH('Form Responses 1'!E2:I, "(?i)Option")), {1;1;1;1;1})}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"), 2, 0), 
 VLOOKUP(A2:A, QUERY({TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 REGEXEXTRACT('Form Responses 1'!C2:C, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, "("&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(UNIQUE(
 FILTER({Sheet3!B2:B; Sheet3!A2:A}, {Sheet3!B2:B; Sheet3!A2:A}<>""))), " ", ").+(")&")"))),,9^9))) , 
 MMULT(N(REGEXMATCH('Form Responses 1'!E2:I, "(?i)Option")), {1;1;1;1;1})}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"), 2, 0)), 0)))
```

Comment: First, thank you for offering to help - it's great seeing what others do so I can learn from your knowledge!

However, the formula you provided didn't provide the same values as when I had a non-array-formula, which did 5 queries and added them together, which I then had to copy down the column (and that *may* be the easiest way to solve this one)...

I've updated the sample google sheet with a column E, and set up conditional formatting to show where the numbers didn't match.